# Is there a proposed name for 1e-4 bitcoins?

Tags: terminology, divisibility

One satoshi is 1e-8 bitcoins. Given that, it appears to me very convenient to have a name for 1e-4 bitcoins, and I'm wondering if someone already proposed or started using a name for that.

*(the SI doesn't have a name for that, being m=1e-3 and µ=1e-6...)*

Comment: That makes sense.  We have millibits (10e-3), but no name yet for the thing where 1 millibit = 10 something else.

Comment: I fixed the notation in the question. It's either 10^(-8) or 1e-8, not 10e-8.

Comment: On a related note, these two are my suggestions; (1) using single currency symbol; subfix / superfix 1, 2, 3 to distinguish among micro / mega units. (2) get two symbols approved; B & b. BTC 0.1=1b100; 0.003=1b3; 0.00004=2b40; 0.000000009=3b9; 1234=1B1.234; 5670000=2B5.67

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a prefix for 10000, *myria*, though it is not part of the SI standard and has effectively been deprecated.  But this means that it is ripe for reuse.  So a myriasatoshi (myria or myrisat for short, I guess) would be 10<sup>-4</sup> bitcoins.

Comment: Well, until someone comes up with a nicer name, I guess we'll have to make it do with this one...

Comment: 'Myria' is no doubt based on the Greek word 'myriad'. http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myriad so that is actually a pretty good word for 10,000. A myriad of Satoshi could be abbreviated and anglicised to a 'miri' or 'mirisat'.

Comment: So that would be: 1 milli = 10 miri.Hmm they sound a bit too similar when you say them out loud.

Comment: I really like this.

Comment: @ColinDean - I like it less than I might given that Japanese does not have distinct r and l consonants.  That's also why I didn't drop the trailing a.

Comment: Just calling them "**myr**" might be cool enough to catch...

Answer (score 2):

Well, a thousand grams is a kilogram.   A thousand sats (Satoshis) is [a kilosat](http://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=8282.msg932168#msg932168).  So 10,000 sats would be ten kilosats.   Maybe that would work.

This assumes when that is needed we are moving away from fractions of a bitcoin and moving towards multiples of Satoshis.

There was also [proposal](http://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=8282.msg121247#msg121247) to call it a milray.  And a number of votes were cast for calling it a lilbit (as in Littlebit).

When a name is found, the [entry for it in the FAQ](http://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/FAQ#What_do_I_call_the_various_denominations_of_bitcoins.3F) should get updated.